# Symfony 2.0: the css, images, javascript doesn't load when my site is online

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I have published my site and I have this inside .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

and when I go to www.mysite.com(example) it doesn't load css, javascript,
images. My files are in "web" folder and I use this code for load them - {{ asset....

Why it does not work?

PS: I can't modify `httpd.conf` on the server because I use shared hosting.

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to access the images, css, javascript directly ex: http://www.mysite.com/css/style.css, if it works, then you typed the wrong src url and shouldn't be the .htaccess. If not, check permissions, clean cache.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using assetic, you should execute

```
./app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```